# Conditional accessing of classes based on constructor parameter

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

```
from folder.test.test1 import Test1
from folder.test.test2 import Test2
from other_folder import Test3

class Sample(Test1, Test2, Test3):
    def __init__(self, version):
        Test3.__init__(self)

        if version == 'gen1':
            self.__class__ = Test1
            Test1.__init__()
        elif version == 'gen2':
            self.__class__ = Test2
            Test2.__init__()

    def login(self, ip):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ob = Sample(version='gen2')
    ob.login('192.168.1.100')
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Test2' object has no attribute 'login'
```

Not able to access the `login()` method of class `Sample`, though I have a `Sample` class object.

I want the object to have access to `Sample`, `Test2` and `Test3` methods (Not of `Test1`, as the version is `'gen2'`). In case the version is `'gen1'`, the `Sample` object shall be having access to only `Sample`, `Test1` and `Test3` methods and not of `Test2`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to split it into 2 classes (if you can):

```
class BaseSample(Test3):
    def login(self, ip):
        pass

class SampleGen1(Test1, BaseSample):
    pass

class SampleGen2(Test2, BaseSample):
    pass
```

And then use the appropiate class in your code:

```
if version == 'gen1':
    ob = SampleGen1()
elif version == 'gen2':
    ob = SampleGen2()
ob.login('192.168.1.100')
```

Would that work for you?